# Why is Tkinter missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Started messing with Tkinter today, but when I tried to run my first program it crashed. It appears the reason is that I don't have Tkinter. This is a standard installation of Python 3.3 on Windows 7, why is it not there? How can I get it?

Comment: Please post any errors you are getting.

Comment: make sure you are importing in lower case, that is 'tkinter' and not 'Tkinter'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer might be irrelevant with more information, but, for now: are you capitalizing "Tkinter" when using the import command?  In Python 3.x, it's imported as lower-case ("import tkinter"), but in 2.x code it's imported with an initial capital ("import Tkinter").

Comment: Bleh. I should most likely find a Python 3 tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: Just faced the same issue now and glad that someone asked the same question some 5 hours back :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you disabled it during Python installation? It is Tcl/Tk item in install wizard and it can be disabled. Try reinstall Python and do not turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the answers above are perfectly good ideas but if neither of these work make sure you are using this code:

```
    from tkinter import *
```

Rather than this code:

```
    import tkinter
```